# NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined(psycopg2)(postgresql)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Не могу решить ошибку... Вот  мой код (работаю с postgresql):

```
conn=connection.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXESTS superheroes")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ass")

conn.commit()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE superheroes (hero_id serial PRIMARY KEY,hero_name varchar,strength int);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO superheroes (hero_nam,strength0VALUES(%s,%s)",("Superman",100))

cunn.commit()
```

И ошибка:

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXESTS superheroes")
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

Comment: и какое слово не понятно в "name 'cursor' is not defined"? ))

Comment: так я как не менял его (и на cur и на cursor) и ничего не помогает(

Answer (score 1):

может так хотели?

```
cur=connection.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXESTS superheroes")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ass")

cur.commit()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE superheroes (hero_id serial PRIMARY KEY,hero_name varchar,strength int);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO superheroes (hero_nam,strength0VALUES(%s,%s)",("Superman",100))

cur.commit()
```

Comment: да большое спасибо)))

Comment: `EXESTS` заработало тоже??? o_O

Answer (score 1):

```py
    # вы сначала коннектитесь
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                  password="pass",
                                  host="localhost",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="p_db")

    # потом создаете курсор для операций
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # выполняете SQL запросы
    cursor.execute("SELECT version();")

    # читаете результат
    record = cursor.fetchone()
```

т.е. ваше `connection.cursor()` - это курсор, а не `conn`

Comment: большое спасибо)))

Comment: @SBNN, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)